# Memory leak when using coroutineScope

Tags: kotlin, out-of-memory

I have encountered an application that appears to be suffering from a memory leak when one of the methods that asynchronously calls an api uses a coroutineScope. The problem goes away when i omit it

The following piece of kotlin code reproduces a memory leak that I am seeing in an application:

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers
import kotlinx.coroutines.async
import kotlinx.coroutines.coroutineScope
import kotlinx.coroutines.runBlocking

class MyApp {

    suspend fun run() {
        myReport()
        // while this is sleeping trigger a heapdump with visual vm
        Thread.sleep(1000000000)
    }

    suspend fun myReport(): List<String> = runGaqlRequest().map { "some keyword" }

    suspend fun runGaqlRequest(): List<String> = io {
        listOf("A".repeat(300_000_000))  // very large string using 80% of a 1024mb heap
    }

    suspend inline fun <R> io(crossinline body: suspend () -> R): R =
        coroutineScope { async(Dispatchers.IO) { body() }.await() }
}

fun main() {
    val app = MyApp()

    runBlocking {
        app.run()
    }
}
```

The `runGaqlRequest` method simulates reading a response from an API endpoint. Here it will return a list with a single element in it. A huge 300.00.000 character string

The `myReport` method transforms each element in this list to the string "some keyword" so the output of this function is a list with a single element "some keyword" element

I invoke `myReport` from a `run` method, that then goes to sleep for a very long time

At this point I would expect the huge string to be eligible for garbage collection however when I use visualvm to create a heapdump of the process i see its still there and unable to be garbage collected

[image: heap dump]

When I change the runGaqlRequest method to this

```
    suspend fun runGaqlRequest(): List<String>  {
        return listOf("A".repeat(300_000_000))  // very large string using 80% of a 1024mb heap
    }
```

So it does not use the coroutineScope the problem goes away.

Edit: I created this repository that can reproduce the problem

https://github.com/jelmerk/reproduce-kotlin-problem

Comment: How do you know it can't be garbage collected? We don't know when exactly the GC will clean up the memory. Try running the code e.g. 20 times with 10s delays between them or so and then check if it crashed due to OOM or you see all 20 strings in the memory.

Comment: BTW, your `io` function doesn't make too much sense. It is effectively simply: `withContext(Dispatchers.IO)`.

Comment: I think visual vm does a "live" dump and only active objects on the heap are dumped

I did not write the io function (its from a piece of code someone else wrote)

If i change it to 
`
suspend inline fun <R> io(crossinline body: suspend () -> R): R =
    withContext(Dispatchers.IO) { body() }
`

The problem also goes away. (which is what chat gpt suggested) I am still trying to understand whats going on though

Comment: `suspend inline fun <R> io(crossinline body: suspend () -> R): R = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) { body() } ` does *not* make the problem go away on my end.  Replacing `io` with `coroutineScope` does however

Comment: @possum, it wouldn’t. broot was just pointing out that code was unnecessarily convoluted and therefore sort of nonsensical. It has two levels of redundant indirection (async followed immediately by await, and `coroutineScope` with effectively a single function call within it) that don’t achieve anything.

Comment: `run()` is marked suspend but blocks. This is breaking the suspend contract so it could cause issues. The `io` function, aside from the convolution is weird because all it achieves is calling the passed suspend function with a dispatcher, which theoretically should do nothing because suspend functions typically specify their dispatcher or method of suspending internally, so they would override this other dispatcher.

Comment: @Tenfour04 I agree and I was referring to jelmer's comment above mine where they were saying it did

Comment: After looking into it, I can only say I believe @Jelmer is correct and it somehow keeps the reference to the string. It doesn't surprise me the reference is kept somewhere in the coroutines machinery, because it has to be stored in the continuation. What surprises me however is that it keeps the continuation itself, as it is related to a function which already returned. After replacing `sleep()` with `delay()` problem goes away, so maybe coroutines do some kind of a cleanup only after suspending. But I don't really know.

Comment: @broot I might not be entirely correct but AFAIK continuation does keep "label" of current suspending point and result of last suspending call. `run` function here is suspending so after `myReport` ends continuation is in state where it has label for post-myReport and result is return value of myReport. Problem here is when continuation encounters thread sleep it freezes with last result still in memory. If I imagine correctly then putting a delay (even before sleep) will move the label forward and overwrite the result with result of delay (Unit I believe) which will free up the "big string".

Comment: @Pawel Hmm, suspending machinery is still pretty confusing to me, but AFAIK, the label you mention is stored separately in each continuation and each function call creates its own continuation. Continuations of callees know about continuations of callers, but not the other way around. After returning from a function there shouldn't be a need to keep the continuation of the function that just returned. By looking into VisualVM, it seems someone still keeps a reference to the continuation of `myReport` and `coroutineScope`, but I have no idea who exactly.

Comment: Maybe this is somehow related to the fact that relationships between coroutine jobs are two way - children know about parents and parents know about children. Somewhere in the job tree there was a connection from the caller coroutine to the coroutine running in `async`. That probably shouldn't mean referencing its continuations, but... well, I don't really know, I'm just speculating.  It looks like it didn't have a chance yet to do the proper cleanup. And it feels to be some kind of a bug or unexpected behavior in coroutines.

Comment: @possum you are right i was mistaken. using withContext did not make the problem go away

Comment: I uploaded a version with the convoluted code removed here: https://github.com/jelmerk/reproduce-kotlin-problem/tree/main

And the problem still exists